# Android RecyclerView circular reveal animation

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

How to implement RecyclerView ItemAnimator so that when the new item is added it appears with circular reveal animation like in the example below.

https://media.giphy.com/media/xT9IgIHforlj3uTwD6/giphy.gif

Comment: Try using Scaleintop animation from recyclerview animator by Wasabeef

Answer (score 1):

En el onClick even you can call to circularReveal:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
   public static void circularReveal(View v){
       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
           int finalRadius = Math.max(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight()) / 2;
           TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition((ViewGroup) v);
           Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(v, v.getWidth() / 2, v.getHeight() / 2, 0, finalRadius);
           anim.start();
       }
   }
```